# How to synchronize two timers on PIC16F1827

Tags: timer, pic, microchip, mplab, xc8

I just got into PIC-programming on Microchips MPLAB X IDE. My programm requires two timers. TMR4 has an interrupt interval of 500ms and TMR2 interrupts every second. When starting the program, the two timers are synced up, so within a small margin of error, when the TMR4 interrupts for the second time, TMR2 also executes the interrupt code. But when I stop TMR2 for a period of time and then start it again, the two timers are completely out of Sync.

Is there a way to resynchronize the two timers or to restart them?

Answer (score 0):

**Why are you stopping the timers?**

There is no need to be stopped when interrupt happened. `TMR2` and `TMR4` are functional identical. When the interrupt is triggered the `TMR2IF` or `TMR4IF` is set. If also set `TMR2IE` or `TMR4IE` then the interrupt is triggered.

The registers `PR2` and `PR4` (also prescaler) must be set according to desired frequency. The value of `TMR2` or `TMR4` is compared to that of the period register, `PR2` or `PR4`, on
each clock cycle. When the two values match, the comparator generates a match signal as the timer output and trigger interrupt, `TMR2IF` or `TMR4IF` is set. If also set `TMR2IE` or `TMR4IE` then the interrupt is triggered. This signal also resets the value of `TMR2` or`TMR4` counters to 0 and timers continue running. When you finish your interrupt program just clear `TMR2IF` or `TMR4IF` to enable next timer interrupt.

If you wont to resynchronize the timer then just reset the `TMR2` and `TMR4` registers value to 0. If you wont to resynchronize in main program then first disable interrupts clear `TMR2` and `TMR4` and enable interrupts again.